# Create a menu based on GridLayout Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to achieve following UI: a home page with static images and text.

[image]

I first came up with tablelayout but it wasn't totally flexible in case the layout changing. Then gridlayout came up, but it is still cannot be mocked exactly same the screenshot.

So my question is which layout suits the best ?

PS: The images are not the same size and consistent each other.

Comment: that could be made fairly easily with relative layout.

Comment: The problem is those images are pretty large. I need to scale them responsively with any screen sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:weightSum="2"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Special"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:text="Dishes"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:text="Event"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:text="Location"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I followed ur layout but it ends up like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10120454/captures/ScreenCapture%20at%20Sat%20Oct%205%2013%3A04%3A19%20EST%202013.png

Comment: layout alinment is mssing i have changed layout structure try now

Comment: Yes, I recognised the missing of positioning in ur layout and changed it but it is still screwed. The main problem is those images are not the same size and pretty large. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10120454/captures/ScreenCapture%20at%20Sat%20Oct%205%2013%3A46%3A57%20EST%202013.png